# use of offset in MIPS

Tags: mips, offset

Suppose $t0 stores the base address of word array, $s0 is associated with position, and $s1 is associated with offset.I have to convert the following program segment into Assembly and write down the resulting array content

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
position = 0
offset = 1
while position < 11:
array[position] = array [position + offset]
position = position + 1;
```

so far i have written this-

```
   .data

array:  
 .word 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
  counter:  .word 11

lw $t1,counter
 la $t0,array
li $s0,0
li $s1,1

loop:

beq $s0,$t1,end
lb $s0,0($t0)
add $s0,$s0,@s1
sll $s0,$s0,2
add $s0,$t0,s0
sw $s1,($s0)
addi $s0,$s0,1
addi $t0,$t0,4 
j loop

end:
```

i dont know how to move forward from here , can anyone help

Comment: Pretend you are the computer. Write down the value of each register after each instruction. You might notice that you are using `$s0` for two conflicting purposes simultaneously.

Comment: I tried to make changes , however i dont understand where am i going wrong

Comment: My mistake, you are using `$s1` to hold the offset, not `$s0`. But still, it's not sure what your question is. The way you move forward from here is to (1) see if the code works, and (2) if not, debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
               .data

        array:  
         .word 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
          counter:  .word 44   # 11 *4 bytes
        .text
        .globl main

        main:
        lw $t1,counter
        la $s0,array # array[i]
        la $s1,array # 
        add $s1,$s1,4 # array[i+1]
        la $s2,array
        li $s3,0  # position
        li $s4,4   # offset = 4 bytes
        li $t4,0
        loop:

        beq $s3,$t1,end
        add $t4,$s3,$s4 # $t4 = position + offset
        lw $t3,($s1)
        sw $t3,($s0)
        add $s0,$s0,4
        add $s1,$s1,4
        add $s3,$s3,4
        j loop

        end:


          li $a0, 0
          li $v0, 17              #exit
          syscall
```